# How to pass stored procedure parameter into EXECUTE statement

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Test"(character varying[],character varying[])
RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
curr refcursor;
filter text;
counter integer;
BEGIN
    counter = 1;
    filter = '';

    IF array_length($1,1) > 0 THEN
        filter = 'AND ';

        WHILE ($1[counter] <> '') LOOP
                filter = filter||'LOWER('||$1[counter]||'::character varying) LIKE ''%''||LOWER($2['||counter||'])||''%'' AND ';
                counter = counter + 1;
        END LOOP;

        filter = substring(filter FROM 1 FOR (char_length(filter)-4));

        OPEN curr FOR
         EXECUTE 'SELECT "Reservation".* FROM "Reservation" WHERE "Reservation"."id" > 0 '||filter;
        return curr;
    END IF;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

SELECT "Test"(ARRAY['"Reservation"."status"'],'{"waiting"}');
FETCH ALL IN "<unnamed portal 1>";
```

I tried to print out the query:

```
"SELECT "Reservation".* FROM "Reservation" WHERE "Reservation"."id" > 0 AND LOWER("Reservation"."status"::character varying) LIKE '%'||LOWER($2[1])||'%' "
```

But when it's executed it said that there was no parameter $2. So I realize that it can't access that stored procedure's parameter.

I don't have to worry about the first parameter of sql injection since it's hard coded. But the second param has to be passed into the execution. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that I could pass the parameter into EXECUTE using the "USING" statement.

Here's the final working code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Test"(character varying[],character varying[])
RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
curr refcursor;
filter text;
counter integer;
BEGIN
    counter = 1;
    filter = '';

    IF array_length($1,1) > 0 THEN
        filter = 'AND ';

        WHILE ($1[counter] <> '') LOOP
                filter = filter||'LOWER('||$1[counter]||'::character varying) LIKE ''%''||LOWER($1['||counter||'])||''%'' AND ';
                counter = counter + 1;
        END LOOP;

        filter = substring(filter FROM 1 FOR (char_length(filter)-4));

        OPEN curr FOR
         EXECUTE 'SELECT "Reservation".* FROM "Reservation" WHERE "Reservation"."id" > 0 '||filter USING $2;
        return curr;
    END IF;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

SELECT "Test"(ARRAY['"Reservation"."status"'],ARRAY['no-show']);
FETCH ALL IN "<unnamed portal 1>";
```

Note that I have $1 as the value in the EXECUTE statement, because it accepts $2 as its first parameter.